# Why does Patch 145006 take so long to install?

Tags: updates, solaris

I'm an engineer in a data centre. My main task is applying updates to server operating systems. One of the operating systems I deal with on a regular basis is Solaris 10.

My Solaris expert colleague (let's call him Bob) can't answer this so I thought I'd put the question to SE.

Occasionally we get called on to do a weekend update of Solaris 10 to what's known as the "Recommended Patchset". Bob prearranges to have the patchset unzipped and available over NFS. Then we install the patchset and go home.

The patchset is a list of package updates (407 at last count) which apply or skip in strict order. On our platforms, most of the packages are skipped since we keep fairly up to date. Skipping a package is much faster than installing one. Installing a package usually takes a few minutes, so the whole lot takes a couple of hours.

We've noticed though that every time, upwards of an hour is taken by a single update called patch 145006 (current revision 145006-09). It takes even longer on boxes with zones installed. We've identified 145006 as an update to Webmin. We've come to dread the appearance of the number 145006.

**(tl;dr)**
Why does it take so long? What can it possibly be doing for an hour? The platform hardware is reasonably fast (eg. RAIDed SAS disks). We're utterly mystified as to why that one patch takes so long to apply. Google apparently knows nothing, the Solaris website is unhelpful and the Webmin website does not tell me anything.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Thanks.

Comment: Run it under `truss` - `truss -f -a -l -d -o /path/to/some/output/file ...`.  Just make sure the output file is on a file system big enough to hold a lot of output.  Then go through all that output and try to figure out what takes so long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is mostly to do with this patch having more files than any other patch; it has on the order of 25k files, while it's rare for one to exceed 5k.  Solaris seems to go through a slow but sure method of backing up each file it replaces and then making sure the new file is synchronized to stable storage; with this many files, it really breaks down.